# Agent to customer message transformation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have two client sides like

1.Agent and customer

2.In Agent .I put a google cdn of socket

3.In customer also.I put a google cdn of socket

4.In Agent Transfers the messages from  to nodejs server sends to customer

5.But the customer is out the website .

1. I write this code in node js server side

   ```
       app.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
       if(arraySockets.length<2){
           arraySockets.push(socket);
           if(arraySockets.length==1){
               SocketAgent = arraySockets[0];
           }
           if(arraySockets.length==2){
               SocketUser = arraySockets[0];
           }
       }

       if(arraySockets.length==2) {
           console.log("dffjdsg");
           console.log(socket.id);
           SocketUser.on('user', function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               var data = {
                      message: 'i am from server'
                }
           });

           SocketAgent.on('agent', function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               var data = {
                      message: 'i am from server'
               }
               SocketUser.emit('outputuser',data);
           });
       }
   });
   ```
2. Code on Agent side

services.js file in client Agent side:

```
    schatApp.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {  
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8089/');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            });
           }
          }; 
        });
```

controller side code in Agent side

```
    schatApp.controller('homeController', function($scope,socket) {

        socket.on('ouputuser',function(data){
            alert(data);
        });

        $scope.Sendingmessage=function(){
            var data={message:'hai simhachalam from  agent'};
            socket.emit('agent',data);
        }
    });
```

Client side code in customer side code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8089/');
        $("#sendmessage").click(function(){
            var data={message:'iam from user'};
            socket.emit('user',data);
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am receiving the messages from Agent to nodes server and customer to node server.
when I exchanging the messages socket object is overriding. So how can I solve the problem

```
socket.on('ouputuser',function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

data is not getting from the node js server